# PHP Object Array from API call

Tags: php, arrays, api, stdclass

I have made an API call `$client->orders->get()` and I get a response with the data formatted like:

```
Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 5180 [order_number] => 5180 [created_at] => 2016-12-21T14:50:08Z [updated_at] => 2016-12-21T15:01:51Z [completed_at] => 2016-12-21T15:01:52Z [status] => completed [currency] => GBP [total] => 29.00 [subtotal] => 29.00 [total_line_items_quantity] => 1 [total_tax] => 0.00 [total_shipping] => 0.00 [cart_tax] => 0.00 [shipping_tax] => 0.00 [total_discount]...........
```

So I loop through the data:

```
foreach ( $client->orders->get() as $order ) {

// skip guest orders (e.g. orders with customer ID = 0)
print_r($order);
    echo $order[0];
    echo $order->subtotal;
}
```

Trouble I have is outputting the data, if I use the print_r function I get an output but I don't know how to access the individual elements of the array.

If I try:

```
echo $order[0].[id];
```

I get:

Catchable fatal error: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string in.

I have searched high and low on this but I just can't find anything I understand. Help please... :)

Comment: ITs PHP not javascript so do `$order[0]->id`. Basicly you `get()` an ARRAY whit one OBJECT on array-index 0.

Comment: Ah ok so it's an array of objects $order[0] is object one and the element/property is accessed with ->id. This does return the id: 5180 but I still get an error:

Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in

Comment: Witch line? What code? Look for `$order[0]['id'];`, and learn the basic syntax of PHP, please :)

Comment: I'm not asking because I'm lazy I'm asking because I don't understand. I really appreciate you have taken the effort to help but I followed your advice and I don't understand how I get an output and an error on the same line.

Line 107 is: echo $order[0]->id;

And this is the error: 5180
Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in test.php on line 107

Comment: OK, what i missed/mixed here was that the first ouput above. I thought it was a direct output of `var_dump($client->orders->get());` because you sayed *I get a response with*, but it was output of `print_r($order);`.  And that was also not noticed by the checked answer down here, and you also sayed that you have to do `foreach($order as $order_details){echo $order_details->subtotal;}` to get it fully work. :-) But since you are fine, everthing is good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The *`$order`* within the following loop

*`foreach ( $client->orders->get() as $order ) { .. }`*

is each of elements that belongs to this *`$client->orders->get()`* array and they are in the form of object.

thus to output ( for e.g the *`subtotal`* entry) you do *`echo $order->subtotal`* :

```
foreach ( $client->orders->get() as $order ) { $order->subtotal }
```

- `echo $order[0]` (*inside* the loop) is  invalid, because doing so is treating the `$order` as an array meanwhile its type is *object*. Do `$order->somefields` instead to reference its properties.
- `print_r($order)` (*inside* the loop) is valid because you can use *print_r* to print the properties of object.
- `$client->orders->get()[0]->subtotal` (if put *outside* the loop) is also valid.

Just in case the array's elements contains both form of *object* or *array*

```
$myarray = $client->orders->get();
```

- `// True because the first element is object
  echo (is_object($myarray[0])) ? 'True':'False';`
- `// False because the first element is object, not an array
  echo is_array($myarray[0]) ? 'True':'False';`

And for this

```
// the same with echo is_array($client->orders->get()) ? 'True':'False';
echo is_array($myarray) ? 'True':'False';
```

sure that would be true, .

Comment: Thanks so much for the explanation that makes so much more sense now however ha ha... I did try this way:

foreach ( $client->orders->get() as $order ) {echo $order->subtotal;}

This does not give an error but also it does not give any output. 

It's definitely a valid field, the first object in the Array has  [subtotal] => 29.00 and this is repeated in the objects. I also get the same response for all fields.

Comment: OK so I worked it out finally, I had to loop through the $orders object to get the order items

foreach($order as $order_details){echo $order_details->subtotal;}

Thanks for the nudge, really appreciate your help.

Comment: Okay you're welcome. I couldn't reproduce your problem at the time as I don't have your array so I tried to explain everything you need so in the future you can walk by yourself and keep your head up :P . Btw I added more information, just in case you want to iterate varying array where the elements could be either *object* or *array*, hope it will benefit you later.

Comment: Thanks so much Jan, I understand so much better now. I can read and read  and not get anywhere, sometimes just an explanation on a practical example makes it all drop into place. So thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You can access the subtotal column value without using foreach loop. Here is the code.

```
$response = $client->orders->get();
$subtotal = $response[0]->subtotal;
```

If you would like to use foreach then you can access like this.

```
foreach ( $client->orders->get() as $order ) {
 echo $order->order_number;
}
```